# How to add <br> in mail section of WordPress CF7

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get line breaks to properly display in the e-mails that the CF7 plugin generates. I am basically trying to dynamically generate a list of items to send through mail, based on what the user checks off on the front end. I am storing that list as a text string with `<br>` tags in a CF7 hidden input.

So, for example, the idea is to get a string like the following into the hidden input, and then display line breaks in mail:

```
item 1 <br>
item 2 <br>
item 3 <br>
```

And so on...and then the hidden input becomes like this

```
<input type="hidden" val="item 1 <br> item 2 <br> item 3 <br>">
```

However, when I receive the e-mail, I just see the "`<br>`" tags in plain text, but I need that to actually be line breaks. I tried checking the option to display the email in HTML format within the plugin's mail settings.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the "Use HTML content type" box below the Message Body field.

Alternatively, just start a new line without the `<br>` tag, that works in most instances.

Comment: I already tried ticking that checkbox. How can I add a new line in the val of an input? The data is coming from the hidden input's val, which is generated through JS on the fly. It's not coming from the plugin's mail field.